# listview with selector property doesnot change properly while scroling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-selector

I am working on listview with selector property, when the user selects the index position that index position should be highlighted  until i select the next index position of listview, selector property works with this one but when i scroll my list view the selector doesnot works as it moves on the top . please help me with this

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@color/selected_color"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" >
    </ListView>

lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //view.setSelected(true);
                Log.d("das","dasdas");
                if(lastSelected != null) {
                    lastSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//(dr/*id of your unselected drawable*/);
                }
                lastSelected = (ViewGroup)view;
                lastSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_color/*id of your selected drawable*/);
               // selectedRow=position; 
                String photo =datasource.getImagePathFromSubMenuId(SubMnuIdlst.get(position));
                Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ofFilePath+"/"+photo);
                Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theImage, 300,250, true);
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapScaled);
                imgMainItem.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); 
                Imagename=ServerPath+"images/"+photo;
                String Desc=datasource.getSubMenuDescriptionFromSubMenuId(SubMenuid12);
                tvDesc.setText(Desc);
                selectionPos=position;
                selectedimgpath=photo;
                menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("SelPos",""+selectionPos);
            }
        });
```

[image: Left side of image is the listview]

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should track the lastSelected position, and in listView's onItemClickListener deselect the lastSelected postion and select the current one.. something like this

```
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(/* id of listView */);
ViewGroup lastSelected = null;
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(
@Override
onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View childView, int pos) {
    if(lastSelected != null) {
        lastSelected.setBackgroundDrawable(/*id of your unselected drawable*/);
    }
    lastSelected = (ViewGroup)childView;
    lastSelected.setBackgroundDrawable(/*id of your selected drawable*/);
    }
 ));
```

Comment: Sorry, its lastSelected

Comment: -Abhishek Shukla i have removed selector property from my xml. when i first click on any index it works but as soon i click on next index nothing gets selected

Comment: setBackgroundResource i have use

Comment: Dude, you are setting colors, not drawables.

Comment: – Abhishek Shukla can you provide me a sample drawble

Comment: You can set color like this: view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse(/* value of color*/));

Comment: – Abhishek Shukla there is a problem with this one when i scroll the listview the new index value is again seleceted, which should not happen.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point.. May your query revolves around viewHolder?

Comment: – Abhishek Shukla when i am scrolling the listview.. it index position of selected value changes